# how can run mvc project with exe?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to run my project, which I wrote with .net mvc, on localhost with the help of an exe. example [Duplicati](https://github.com/duplicati/duplicati).
I've been searching for a long time but couldn't find it

Comment: Would this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#self-contained-deployment

Comment: not help this cause this is .net forms but i use asp.net or mvc web app

Comment: Is the app using .NET Core? In that case you can use those linked dotnet publish commands to make a self-contained exe?

Comment: juunas yes use .net core. but how can self-contained exe